# Does property allocate memory with `get` only?

Tags: c#, memory, properties

For example,

`public int Health { get; set; }`

Allocates 4 bytes.

Will `public int Health { get { return ..... } }` allocate any memory?

Or is it simply a method that returns `int` value?

Comment: It's simply a method that returns an int value. But why do you care? are you working on a machine that was manufactured back in the 1980, where 4 bytes was a thing?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have 2 options, make some fields properties because their values can be calculated from formula or send calculated values from server and use them. I would like to reduce the size of the package from the server while keeping the syntax of property instead of making many methods.

Comment: @CandidMoon By how many bytes, total, do you expect to reduce "the size of the package from the server" (?) by saving four bytes on each property? 10? 100? 1,000? 10,000? Just a rough order of magnitude estimate.

Comment: @Servy I asked here because the amount of objects isn't that big to see the memory change right away without proper benchmarking, but those objects are updated frequently from the server. It's not that big of a performance issue for the projects, but it would save lots of time because I wouldn't need to change properties to method calls in many scripts. Unless I can handle that by changing the `name` directly to `method()` but that would mess up some comments and other script references.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The server sends JSON that is being parsed afterwards. I have around 20 properties that would require to be sent to client with 1 package for 1 object.

Comment: @CandidMoon You can't have it both ways.  Either it's a big enough performance impact that it would be trivially measurable, or it's not a performance impact and you can ignore it.  It can't both be an impactful performance change without being easily measurable.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It is, I'm not that experienced with multi-player, but I couldn't find information right away about that. What solution would you choose to reduce the size or the size doesn't matter in this case? Anyway it would be helpful for anyone searching for this kind of question without having to make benchmarking. Thank you for your answer, though :)

Comment: @Servy The question you marked as a duplicate isn't quite descriptive. They aren't providing any real explanation to this. They are talking about auto-properties and the properties that are referencing another object. I was asking about auto-property with `getter` only. No object referencing.

Comment: @Servy could you please show me the exact lines that answer my question from that other question? If no, please remove your duplicate tag. If you were right, I will accept that this question is duplicate and ask for it to be closed.

Comment: @CandidMoon The whole answer is an answer to your question.  It contains just two sentences.  I trust that you can read both of those sentences, rather than assuming that the question won't answer your question without having even read them.  If it was actually longer than 40 words then I could maybe understand the hesitation...

Comment: @Servy "As I've understand it when you instantiate an object each value field occupies its size and reference field types 4 bytes per field. But say you have an object with 1000 properties that fetches data via some other object, does those properties occupy any memory in themselves?" - Hmm, what if I do that - ` public int Lol { get { return 2 + 1; } set { this.Lol = value; } }
` - it falls into that question, it will create an infinite loop, but still the allocation will be there.

Comment: @CandidMoon You can read the answer to the duplicate to see the answer to that question.  It tells you whether that example will affect the allocation size of the object or not.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, back then I couldn't express what I really wanted to understand, this was a poor quality question. `public int Property { get { return 4; } }` will allocate some memory for constant value. While I thought that `public int Property { get { return x + y + 4; } }` - will cache value calculated per instance instead of computing it every time. My lack of understanding lead to this confusion. Thanks for marking it duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties do not increase the per-instance size of the allocation, in the same way that adding methods does not require additional per-instance memory.

> I have 2 options, make some fields properties because their values can be calculated from formula or send calculated values from server and use them. I would like to reduce the size of the package from the server while keeping the syntax of property instead of making many methods.

This is a common trade-off where you can decide to pay with memory for a reduction in CPU use, or store more data to save on computation. The answer depends on your constraints for memory, CPU use, and network, and requires profiling of both options.

If the server computes the value that it sends you, as opposed to sending you a stored value, the trade-off becomes somewhat more complex. Since you have the same computation both on the server and on the client, maintaining the two in sync becomes a maintenance liability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right now I don't have problems with CPU performance, but I would like to reduce the amount of time I need to get data from server. Plus I wouldn't need to write additional code that fills the fields on the server side. I check all the values on the server if they are correct anyway or simply use the ones that are stored on server.